# display a table when a button is pressed

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I'm working on a web application that display information from a database.
I want to display a table in HTML page using PHP and SQL Server Database
but when I press the button nothing appears and I don't know why. Here's my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style_wbr.css"/>
        <title>PORTAIL</title>
    </head>
<body>

  <h1 id ="titre">Reporting</h1>
  <img id="image" src="http://www.tessares.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/sa.png" >



  <form method="post" action="/authentification.php">
  <div class="quit">
        <input type="submit" name="quit" id="quit" value="Quitter"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="button" id ="historique" name="historique" value="Historique"/>
  </div>

  </form>
<br></br>
<br></br>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['historique']))
{

  $rqt = "SELECT TOP (10) DEP_Operation.id, DEP_Operation.operationDate, DEP_Users.fullName
FROM  DEP_Operation INNER JOIN
               DEP_Products ON DEP_Operation.productID = DEP_Products.id INNER JOIN
               DEP_Errors ON DEP_Operation.errorID = DEP_Errors.id INNER JOIN
               DEP_Users ON DEP_Operation.personInCharge = DEP_Users.id";
      $stmt = mssql_query($rqt);
?>
<table id="tab" border="1">


                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Dépanneur</th>
                </tr>
<?php

      while ($data = mssql_fetch_assoc($stmt))
      {

          ?>
          <tr>

                    <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['id']);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['operationDate']);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($data['fullName']);?></td>
          </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
<?php
}
?>



</body>


</html>
```

I deleted the code of the database connection because I have no issue with that, and when I run the code without the button test it works. So the issue is with the button test.
Can you help me with this issue please?

Comment: `<input type="button"` is the wrong type.

Comment: did you use any script to hide and show the table?

Comment: you do not need the <input type="botton">, you just need to submit, and check if(isset($_POST['quit']))

Comment: @NaushilJain what u mean by script ??

Comment: @rscata the button is 'historique' and not 'quit' , the button 'quit' it takes me to the authentification page

Comment: a, sorry. you need two forms. One for authentication and one for table

Comment: Something like that

`<form method="post" action="/authentification.php">
  <div class="quit">
        <input type="submit" name="quit" id="quit" value="Quitter"/>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="this_page">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="historique" name="historique" value="Historique"/>
  </div>
</form>`

Comment: problem solved , i added another form with action = '#'

Comment: yes @rscata , that's what i did secondes before i see your comment , thnks anyway